# Angular & Mat-table - How to disable/enable Drag & Drop mode?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material

My material table is with `Drag & Drop` enable. I want add togle button to Disable/Enable this mode.

**My HTML template:**

```
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource | periodicElementFilter:periodicElementFilter" class="mat-elevation-z8"
  cdkDropList
  (cdkDropListDropped)="dropTable($event)">
    ...
</table>
```

**My typeScript component:**

```
enableDragDropMode(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
  // ???
}
```

[image]

Demo online [**HERE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thk7zp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279829/cdkdraganddrop-how-to-prevent-dragging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find solution [**HERE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hrulnj):

[image]

```
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource | periodicElementFilter:periodicElementFilter" class="mat-elevation-z8"
  cdkDropList
  (cdkDropListDropped)="dropTable($event)"
  [cdkDropListDisabled]="dragDisabled">
```

And

```
enableDragDropMode(event: MatSlideToggleChange) {
  this.dragDisabled = !event.checked
}
```

And upgrade Angular to 8.0.3+ and "@angular/material": "8.0.1+"

Answer (score 2):

You can use @Input('cdkDropListDisabled'), which is boolean type and manage it by changing this input value.

Add below code to your table:

```
[cdkDropListDisabled]="yourBooleanProperty"
```

Then inside your enableDragDropMode function change yourBooleanProperty value based on event :)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add this attribute [cdkDragDisabled] = "true".
Reference link
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api